# When can you start wishing people a good weekend?

Tags: business-language, greetings

In Belgian culture (and some others, I suppose) it is not uncommon to wish people a good weekend when you meet them on Friday. Not just when you go home after work, but also in the store around noon, or even in the morning.

Is this common in English too? If you send a business e-mail on Friday, is it weird to end it with "have a good weekend"?

Comment: I believe this would now be better located on Interpersonal Skills.SE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In an email, such "premature" weekend well-wishing would be fine. In fact, you might say that it sort of sends an implicit message, something along the lines of:

(a) I'm not sure if we'll communicate again before the end of the business day, or
(b) I realize you may not read this message until this afternoon.

In other words, I might be *less* likely to close a Friday morning email that way with my secretary or boss (who I normally see every couple hours through the course of the day), and *more* likely to do so in an email to that IT assistant who works on the other side of building (who I may not talk with again until Monday or Tuesday next week).

But no, nothing “weird” about it – not in the U.S., either.

Comment: I've been wished a good weekend on a Thursday by various Europeans, particularly when I was going to next see/talk to them early the following week. Seems unobjectionable.

Comment: @StuartF Objectionable is a bit strong, but it's not entirely unobjectionable to me. On hearing 'have a good weekend', depending on the time/day, it definitely means to me (US) that it is near the weekend and you don't expect to communicate again before then. Also, the weekend starts when you leave work on Friday (or Friday evening). So saying/writing it on Thursday would seem strange unless you really really expect not to talk before the following Monday. Also, if you say it at 3pm on Friday, but then run across each other at 4pm, it feels weird... it's tantamount to 'See you Monday'

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if the practice in Belgium is much the same as it is in the UK.